# Что лучше. Фасад db (сырой, конструктор), модель или объект модели?

Tags: php, laravel

Начинаю познавать фреймворк laravel и возникают вопросы.
Одни из них: Что лучше использовать при работе с бд? Фасад DB (сырой запрос или конструктор), модель или объект модели? Или их нужно как-то грамотно использовать все?
Это если что про MySQL, ну и к PostgreSQL тоже думаю относится.

Comment: Если с моделью работаете, то очевидно, модель. Если с произвольными запросами, то фасад.

Comment: @teran , а обязательно создавать объект? Или всегда можно через статику? И в чем прикол моделей, если можно всё без них делать?

Comment: экземпляр представляет собой по сути конкретную строку таблицы. а статика - саму таблицу. Вот с чем именно работаете, то и использовать надо.

Comment: А мне кажется Вам просто нужно почитать про `MVC`, что это такое, с чем едят. И большая часть вопросов отпадет сама собой.

Comment: @phpBear , я знаком, спасибо.